# Why is npm i -g module different from npm i -g --only=dev .?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Let's say we have this simple `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "tests"
  ],
  "author": "JJ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

Basically we're looking to install mocha as a dependency for development, obviously. We run

```
npm i -g mocha
```

It's installed, and then

```
which mocha
```

works.

However, this does not yield the same result:

```
npm i -g --only=dev .
```

Obviously, it's installing things someplace else which is not in the path, possibly. But how come it's different? Running with `--verbose` does not yield much more information on where exactly it's going to be located.

Anyway, what I'm looking for is is a consistent way of specifying these global requirements. It does not seem too clean to create a Docker image or whatever with lots of npm i -g xxx yyy zzz followed by npm i with a package.json (or package-lock.json) where those dependencies are already specified. Maybe there's another way I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

When you install an npm package with the -g tag, you are installing the package globally on your machine, not in your project;

Only use the -g tag if you are going to run something specific on your machine that isn't required by the project; otherwise, just hit npm i and install it directly on the project directory.

If it's going to be a development dependency, install it with npm install --save-dev mocha